# Redirect permanently 301 in blogengine.net (global.asax)

Tags: blogengine.net

i want to redirect my old address www.informarea.it/BlogEngine to new address www.informarea.it...

**my global.asax of blogengine.net is **

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = app.Context;

   // Attempt to perform first request initialization
    FirstRequestInitialization.Initialize(context);
}
```

**can i make to apply the code of redirect permanently? **

```
if (app.url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://www.informarea.it/BlogEngine")) 
 {

     HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";   

     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",url.Replace("http://www.informarea.it/blogengine", "http://www.informarea.it"));

}
```

Can Someone help me?
thank you very much
Fabry

Answer (score 0):

This should redirect any query where the path starts with /BlogEngine to the same url with the /BlogEngine removed.

```
if(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/BlogEngine", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    Response.RedirectPermanent(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Substring(11), true);
}
```

Pros:

- Gives a 301 Redirect like you requested
- Keeps the rest of the path and query string intact for the following request

Cons:

- Requires .net 4.0 (Version 2.7 of BlogEngine is targeted at 4.0 so I don't think this will be an issue.)